# How to return the number of channels in discord.js?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I would like to know how to return the number of channels in a guild, but removing categories.
Is that possible?
I tried to do this:

```
message.guild.channel.size
```

Comment: SO is not a code writing service. Please add a relevant code snippet of what you tried

Comment: what do you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close, but here is what you do:

```js
//Async Callback
await message.guild.channels.fetch(); //Cache all channels
return message.guild.channels.cache.filter(c => c.type !== 'category').size;
```

Comment: Oh, I didn't knew about cache, ty buddy!3

Comment: I believe you have to use `await message.guild.channels.guild.fetch();` in order to make it work. (discord.js@12.5.3)

Comment: I just put `message.guild.channels.cache.filter(c => c.type !== 'category').size` , it worked normally